# custom class variable returns null when in array

Tags: java, arrays, casting, null

Below are two snippets of code.

When i use Student[] student = new Student[5], the line of code at the end (student[StudentID].inputPref(penalty)) appears to be null after checking its value.
However for the second snippet, if i use Student student = new Student() instead, the variable student.inputPref(penalty) has an address that can be pointed to my class Student.

For my work i need to use Student[] as i have a few student inputs that i need to input and i cant just use Student student, is there anyway to go around this?

```
Student[] student = new Student[5];
private void AddStudentActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    InputPreference(student);
}                                          

private void InputPreference(Student[] student){
    int[] penalty = new int[2];
    int StudentID;

    StudentID = Integer.valueOf(this.id.getText());
    penalty[0]= Integer.valueOf(this.pref1.getText());
    penalty[1]= Integer.valueOf(this.pref2.getText());

    student[StudentID].inputPref(penalty);
}
```

and

```
Student student = new Student();
private void AddStudentActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    InputPreference(student);
}                                          

private void InputPreference(Student student){
    int[] penalty = new int[2];
    int StudentID;

    StudentID = Integer.valueOf(this.id.getText());
    penalty[0]= Integer.valueOf(this.pref1.getText());
    penalty[1]= Integer.valueOf(this.pref2.getText());


    student.inputPref(penalty);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Student[] student = new Student[5];
```

Statement only initializes array not objects in it. You must also initialize each of Student instances in array. For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < student.length; i++)
    student[i] = new Student();
```